# REST API Versioning (V1 / V2 / V3) in Magento 2.3

Tags: rest, api, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

Have clarification on implementing versioning on custom API in Magento 2.3

**Current Scenario:**

- We have implemented custom REST API with some functionality.

  - API Spec:

    - API: https://example.domain.com/rest/default/V1/custom/module/list
    - Method: GET

**Expected Scenario**

- We need to use same functionality with minor change in version 2.

  - API Spec

    - API: https://example.domain.com/rest/default/V2/custom/module/list
    - Method: GET

**Note:**

- The both API end point service method should be a same.
- The current scenario should not be break by handling expected scenario. Both API should be work as we expect.

Hope the below code will help for reference

/app/code/Custom/Module/etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/custom/module/list" method="GET">
        <service class="Custom\Module\Api\StudentInterface" method="getList" />
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

/app/code/Custom/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Custom\Module\Api\StudentInterface" type="Custom\Module\Service\StudentService"/>
</config>
```

/app/code/Custom/Module/Api/StudentInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Api;

interface StudentInterface
{
    /**
     * Get Student list
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getList();
}
```

/app/code/Custom/Module/Service/StudentService.php

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Service;

class StudentService
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getList()
    {
        //To do get Student List
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use same Service Method and return response based on REST API Verisoning (V1 / V2 / V3) ?

Comment: Yes It is working

Comment: @Jinesh, Thanks for your response. How it will work ? what I need to do ?

Comment: you need to create extension like you do in your question

Comment: @Jinesh, You meant duplicate the extension (API Endpoint) as V2 and use same Service with different Method name ..??

Comment: yes you can duplicate it

Comment: @Jinesh, Thanks for your response. Hope that is standard followed in Magento 2 for REST API V2 / V3 / etc.,

Comment: yes It is standard way to work on magento api